# Display Issues with sliding news tap

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem with this sliding tap for news own my website.

[image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Hhc3rb2m0ag/VVGXijdaR1I/AAAAAAAAADY/_uWqTgfSNqM/w426-h237/tapIssue.png]

The problem is that the titles of the articles are over each other....

**CSS:**

```
background: none;
display: inline-block;
list-style: disc;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
color: #fff;
letter-spacing: ;
float: left;
/* width: 300px; */
text-align: left;
}
```

and this's the code for marquee
**CSS:**

```
 display: inline-block;
 width: -webkit-fill-available;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: initial;
 /* width: 300px; */
 float: right;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 /* white-space: nowrap; */
```

**HTML**

```
<ul style="width: auto;">
    <marquee direction="right" scrolldelay="1" onmouseout="scrollAmount=7" onmouseover="scrollAmount=7" scrollamount="7">
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101099">الجيش المصري يفجّر 4 مساجد شمال سيناء</a>
        </li>
        <li style="/* list-style: none; */">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101098">بالصور.. "سبق" ترصد تضرر مساجد نجران من قذائف المليشيات الحوثية</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101097">افتتاح أول مسجد على أطلال كنيسة مهجورة في إيطاليا</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101096">حكم قبض اليدين في الصلاة</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101095">إمامة المسافر بالمقيم</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101094">ترك الصلاة</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;"> 
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101092">حكم تكرار الجماعة في المسجد</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101090">بالصور.. "نورد كمال" أبعد مسجد على الكرة الأرضية</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101089">مسجد النقلة بدير البلح يكرم الملتزمين في صلاة الفجر</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101088">إنشاء أول مسجد مخصص للنساء في بريطانيا</a>
        </li>
    </marquee>
</ul>
```

Comment: Paste the code back, that picture is no good.

Comment: That image you've posted is way too small. It's impossible to see what that is...

Comment: you say you have a problem but I don't see an explanation of the problem. This is currently just a code dump, with a bad example image, which is shouting "FIX ME".

Comment: will, the problem is that ...the titles of the articles are over each other....

Comment: This a clear image sorry
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-z3xhSJRhWco/VVGeHz9plaI/AAAAAAAAAEw/0cc1uM1t8mc/w346-h192/p.png

Comment: it looks like you are not showing all of your css, as what you posted does not overlap when I use the code at http://jsfiddle.net/4n2x8n4t/. So it looks like your issue is not in what you posted, but in what you didn't post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a lot of mistakes. Remove all floats first. Move ul inside marquee. Look at my code snippet:

```css
ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}

marquee {
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-left: 5px;
   padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<marquee direction="right" scrolldelay="1" onmouseout="scrollAmount=7" onmouseover="scrollAmount=7" scrollamount="7">
<ul style="width: auto;">
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101099">الجيش المصري يفجّر 4 مساجد شمال سيناء</a>
        </li>
        <li style="/* list-style: none; */">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101098">بالصور.. "سبق" ترصد تضرر مساجد نجران من قذائف المليشيات الحوثية</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101097">افتتاح أول مسجد على أطلال كنيسة مهجورة في إيطاليا</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101096">حكم قبض اليدين في الصلاة</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101095">إمامة المسافر بالمقيم</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101094">ترك الصلاة</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;"> 
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101092">حكم تكرار الجماعة في المسجد</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101090">بالصور.. "نورد كمال" أبعد مسجد على الكرة الأرضية</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101089">مسجد النقلة بدير البلح يكرم الملتزمين في صلاة الفجر</a>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style: none;">
            <img src="images/logonews.png" width="20" height="20" style="">
            <a href="art.php?id=1010101088">إنشاء أول مسجد مخصص للنساء في بريطانيا</a>
        </li>
</ul>
    </marquee>
```